# After 18th iteration, the loss and validation loss suddenly rise from 0.17 to 0.5 and never reduce from there.. The training has stopped

Tags: keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

I'm training a Deep Learning Model using Tensorflow.keras. The Loss function is Triplet Loss. The optimizer is Adam, with learning rate as 0.00005.

Initially the training Loss was 0.38 and it started converging slowly. At 17th Epoch the val_loss became 0.1705. And suddenly in the 18th Epoch training Loss and val_loss both became 0.5 and the same continued for 5-6 epochs. The Loss values didn't change.

Any insight on this behavior would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For some models, the loss goes down during training, but at some point an update is applied to a variable that drastically changes your models output. If this is the case, sometimes the model is not able to recover from this new state, and the best it can do from then on is to output 0.5 for every input (I assume that you try to do a binary classification task).

Why can these erroneous updates happen even though they are bad for your model? This is because updates are done using gradient descent. Gradient descent uses the first derivative only though. This means, that the model does know how it needs to change a specific variable, but only very close to its current value. If your learning rate is too high, then the update can be to big and your gradient descent update might be very bad for your models performance.

Comment: I'm using very low learning rate 0.00005, and the also reducing the LR over plateau.

Answer (score 0):

I read first as training loss much greater than validation loss. That is underfitting.

I read second as training loss much less than validation loss. That is overfitting.

Not an expert but my assumptions have been

Typically validation loss should be similar to but slightly higher than training loss. As long as validation loss is lower than or even equal to training loss one should keep doing more training.

If training loss is reducing without increase in validation loss then again keep doing more training

If validation loss starts increasing then it is time to stop

If overall accuracy still not acceptable then review mistakes model is making and think of what can one change:

More data? More / different data augmentations? Generative data?
Different architecture?

- Underfitting – Validation and training error high
- Overfitting – Validation error is high, training error low
- Good fit – Validation error low, slightly higher than the training
  error
- Unknown fit - Validation error low, training error ‘high’